# invalid CEN header exception to read ZIP file?

Tags: java, python, zip, epub

I am generating ePub of size more then 2 GB.

I create zip file first and then rename to .epub

I am using zip64

```
zp = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
```

more details: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783643/allowzip64-true-will-work-for-small-size-files`

Then I pass ePub to ePub Checker and this give following exception.

```
FATAL(PKG-008): ./NOID.epub/NOID.epub(-1,-1): Unable to read file 'invalid CEN header (bad signature)'.
```

these means that epub can not read by the `ePub Checker`, so it will not given any error from ePub.

Java Version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.6.4.el6_8-x86_64 u101-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

ePubcheck Version:

```
$ /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.0/webapps/epubcheck4.0.1/epubcheck.jar
```

If Zip i.e. ePub file size is less than 2 GB then this error is not coming, but Zip i.e. ePub file size is more than 2 GB then this error is coming.

where is I am wrong?